# Convert nested dictionary to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to convert a nested dictionary into a pandas df for some stock data I have. The data I am scraping comes in the dictionary as shown below. Apologies it is a very long snippet, I wanted to include all the fields to avoid cutting it incorrectly, plus I may want to include more later.

```
Data = {'data': [{'heading': {'key': 'history.instrument', 'context': {'quantityPrecision': 8, 'baseCode': None, 'prettyName': 'Coca-Cola', 'precision': 2, 'treeType': 'STOCK', 'instrument': 'KO', 'instrumentBadge': None, 'instrumentCode': 'KO_US_EQ'}, 'meta': None}, 'subHeading': {'key': 'history.order.filled.buy', 'context': {'quantityPrecision': 8, 'amount': 10.0, 'quantity': 0.245264, 'amountPrecision': 2}, 'meta': None}, 'mainInfo': {'key': 'history.currency-amount', 'context': {'amount': 10.0, 'currency': 'GBP'}, 'meta': None}, 'additionalInfo': {'key': 'history.order.status.filled', 'context': None, 'meta': {'colour': 'ACCENT', 'uppercase': True, 'multiline': False}}, 'date': '2021-08-26T16:45:10+03:00', 'detailsPath': '/orders/1514731569'}, {'heading': {'key': 'history.instrument', 'context': {'quantityPrecision': 8, 'baseCode': None, 'prettyName': 'First Solar', 'precision': 2, 'treeType': 'STOCK', 'instrument': 'FSLR', 'instrumentBadge': None, 'instrumentCode': 'FSLR_US_EQ'}, 'meta': None}, 'subHeading': {'key': 'history.order.filled.buy', 'context': {'quantityPrecision': 8, 'amount': 11.0, 'quantity': 0.160216, 'amountPrecision': 2}, 'meta': None}, 'mainInfo': {'key': 'history.currency-amount', 'context': {'amount': 11.0, 'currency': 'GBP'}, 'meta': None}, 'additionalInfo': {'key': 'history.order.status.filled', 'context': None, 'meta': {'colour': 'ACCENT', 'uppercase': True, 'multiline': False}}, 'date': '2021-08-26T16:45:09+03:00', 'detailsPath': '/orders/1514731500'}, 'hasNext': True, 'footer': None}
```

I want the output to look like this below in a dataframe.

[image: Desired Output df]

I am getting stuck with attempting to convert the outputted data from a nested dictionary into a pandas dataframe so it is more useable for me.

If I try to put the data straight into a dataframe using:

```
data_2 = pd.DataFrame(Data)
```

I get this output.

[image: Current Output]

Clearly I need to tidy the data when converting to a dataframe but I cannot get the setup correct for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through every item in the main list in your `Data` object and then pick out the pieces you need:

```
data_list=[]

for item in Data:
        print(item)
        data_list.append([item['heading']['context']['prettyName'], item['heading']['context']['instrument'], item['subHeading']['context']['quantity']])

df = pd.DataFrame(data_list, columns=['prettyName','instrument','quantity'])
```

Just add onto that logic to get your remaining columns.

Comment: I get the following error with that code..

   data_list.append([item['heading']['context']['prettyName'], item['heading']['context']['instrument'], item['subHeading']['context']['quantity']])

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: I used your data from the question and didn’t hit the issue. You’ll have to understand how your data is structured in your object to be able to point to it using this method.

Comment: Apologies, I found that the data was slightly different so I have modified the question now. I have tried to run the following but still get the same answer, any ideas? data_list.append([item['data']['heading']['context']['prettyName'],

Comment: Solved it, your answer was 99% of what I needed, thank you!

for item in data['data']:
        print(item)
        data_list.append([item['heading']['context']['prettyName'], item['heading']['context']['instrument']])